# What is the Biblical basis for "7 arguments for Cessationism"?

Tags: biblical-basis, cessationism

Here are the 7 arguments for Cessationism by Tom Pennington reiterate at the Strange Fire conference. (posted on [www.challies.com](https://www.challies.com/liveblogging/strange-fire-conference-a-case-for-cessationism/)) (summarized version)

1. ***The unique role of miracles*** - For authentication of the messenger(s). God worked miracles through unique men - Moses; Elijah and Elisha; Christ and his apostles.
2. ***The end of the gift of apostleship*** - The Apostleship was one the gifts of church offices (1 Cor 12:28; Eph 4), and the gift gone with the death of Apostles.
3. ***The foundational nature of the New Testament apostles and prophets*** - Apostles and prophets laid the foundation of the Christ' Church (Eph 2:20-22).
4. ***The nature of the New Testament miraculous gifts*** - Alleged "miracles" reported after the Apostles are not same type, e.g., disparity between modern day healings and NT healings; "Tongues," gibberish vs. known languages, etc.
5. ***The testimony of church history*** - The practice of apostolic gifts declines even during the lifetimes of the apostles. Even in the written books of the New Testament, the miraculous gifts are mentioned less as the date of their writing gets later.
6. ***The suffucuency of Scripture*** - The Spirit speaks only in and through the inspired Word.
7. ***The New Testament governed the miraculous gifts*** - Whenever the New Testament gifts of tongues was to be practiced, there were specific rules that were to be followed.

For full post by Tim Challies, click above link

Comment: Depends who you ask! Many cessationists would say yes, but most continuationists would say no to at least some of them. So you would need to [edit] this to specify whose perspective you are interested in. If you haven't read it yet, please read [What types of questions can I ask on this site?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/6071)

Comment: I've reopened it, but I think this could well be too broad. Each of those 7 arguments could have a whole question asked about it.